# how to use this WEBAPI in android apps without using any third party tool

Tags: android

My requirement is to fetch the data from SQL Server database to mobile in Android Apps. For fetching data, I have used WEB API and developed this WEB API using VS2012.

While using Web Service, I got the data successfully from database and loaded in android apps. Now I am using WEB API instead of Web-service to fetch data from database.

How to use this WEB API in android apps without using any third party tool?

Comment: what´s "web api" for you? some collection of REST services?

Comment: for, if so, there´s the HttpClient http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 0):

To use API  without third party tools you need to use SDK of web service which is provided by web service. include SDK in your project. you can also use jar file in library.
Or you can see better example from [here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89)